# android: error parsing package

Tags: android, parsing, package

I am downloading an app in Android from a server and saving it to the internal memory:

```
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
// download the file
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir() + "/filename");
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
output.write(data, 0, count);
}
output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

When the download is completed, a notification appears. When the notification is clicked, the app should be installed.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir()+ "/filename")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
PendingIntent act = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity._activity,0, i, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo("TEXT", "TEXT, act);
```

But when I click the notification, a dialog box saying: Error parsing package appears. Why?

Comment: Do you find additional information in logcat?

Comment: yes:  Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation

Comment: I'm having the same issue... I open the FileOutputStream, write, flush, open the intent and bang

Answer (score 1):

Another application with the same package name might be already installed in the device. So you are getting the error.

Comment: no, I am sure that there is no other application with the same package name.

Comment: I think u'r downloaded file is corrupted (or) file from u'r server is corrupted. Did u check about it ??

Comment: whe I tried to download the app from the browser, it works perfectly.